# Wake up Google Glass by alternate method

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

As you know, after a short period of time Google Glass will go into a sleep/hibernation like state where one must swipe the side of the glasses or tilt their head back a minimum of 10 degrees to start using them again.

I have a use case for a handicap individual where they don't have use of their hands (or legs), and can't tilt their head back the full 10 degrees. We measured as best we could, and 7-8 degrees is the best he can do.

I'd like to help this person out with a simple app that wakes up Google Glass in an alternative way. Given his restraints, I was thinking of tying into the accelerometer and waking them up with a simple "shake" of the head ( it would have to be sensitive ), or simply allowing for a way to set it to 7 or 8 degrees instead of the minimum of 10. I figured before diving head first into the GDK and/or Mirror API's, only to find out some sort of "gotcha", I would ask the friendly and resourceful Stackoverflow community if something like this is even possible, and if it is, what those possibilities are.

Thank you to anyone that can add insight.

UPDATE:

I tried Deqing's suggestion. I ended up using [Bluetooth Manager for Glass](http://ddrboxman.github.io/Bluetooth-Manager-for-Glass/), because the settings apk bluetooth card doesn't support anything but Android and iPhone devices. I was able to get to "Pair a New Device", and have it recognize the device, but when I tapped "Pair", it just sits there trying to pair, and nothing really happens. I then found this [google BUG report](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=495), which seems to indicate blue tooth connectivity support was broken in update 19.

Answer (score 0):

If hardware approach is an option, grab a Bluetooth keyboard or a regular USB keyboard + OTG cable. You can wake up Glass via keystroke.